# Why are there so few 7s in the first thousand digits of pi?

Tags: statistics, pi

https://media.giphy.com/media/l378lGXxr17Sc0imA/giphy.gif

This gif shows the disparity. Is it statistically significant? What causes it?

Comment: I don't understand, the gif doesn't show any disparity in favor of 7s. There is a modest disparity in favor of 1s.

Comment: look at the graph.

Comment: Your title suggests an *excess* of 7s, while the animated GIF displays a *paucity* of them.  Should the title be "Why are there so few 7s.."?

Comment: 7 appears *less*, not *more*.

Comment: my bad! thanks Javier.

Comment: Why did you choose 7 as the least represented digit? In the first 1000 digits of $pi$ `0` and `4` appear $93$ times, `6` appears $94$ times and `7` appears $95$ times

Comment: I'm asking about the anomaly in the graph. Is it significant?

Comment: It will maybe be significant if you are able to prove that the percent of some digit does not tend to 10 percent when the number of digits tends to infinity.

Comment: There are issues with that, but I'm just interested in the first 1000 digits. Can this be explained by randomness?

Comment: Perhaps remind yourself what $\pi$ actually is. I doubt the lack of 7's is very significant. Maybe look into the first thousand digits of $e$ if you're willing to put some research effort.

Comment: I wouldn´t even try to explain it with random models.

Comment: Because $\pi$ is not random at all.

Comment: So no one knows why.

Answer (score 1):

An approximate 95% confidence interval for the proportion on 7's among $n = 1000$ independent
trials with $P(7) = 0.1$ at each digit is $0.1 \pm 1.96\sqrt{(.1)(.9)/1000}$ or
$(0.0814, 0.1186)$ so the fraction 0.07 I saw looking at the link is a little
low.

However, there is no reason to suppose that digits of $\pi$ are
independent, identically distributed with probability 0.1 each. 
Perhaps a fairer test would be a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test
checking all ten digits against the equally likely model.

There has been some debate in the mathematical and popular literature about whether the digits of $\pi$ act as if they are random in this way. You can google around and
see which 'authorities' you choose to believe. Once you decide that,
you can ponder the digits of $e,$ and so on for other transcendental numbers.

*Addendum:* Here is an experiment with 1000 digits 0 through 9 from the
well-vetted pseudorandom number generator 'Mersenne twister' implemented
in R statistical software. For the seed I chose, all digits except 2 and 6 have
relative frequencies of occurrence
within the interval shown above.

```
set.seed(1066)
d = sample(0:9, 1000, rep=T)
table(d)/1000
## d
##     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
## 0.092 0.094 0.135 0.094 0.082 0.093 0.121 0.095 0.102 0.092
```

But for a million digits all relative frequencies are accurate to within
the anticipated three decimal places.

```
set.seed(1066)
d = sample(0:9, 10^6, rep=T)
round(table(d)/10^6,4)
## d
##      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9 
## 0.1002 0.0999 0.1000 0.1000 0.1002 0.0997 0.1003 0.1000 0.0997 0.1000
```

Comment: Why only transcendental?

Comment: I was really just wondering if someone had offered an explanation for this yet.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Well, no proven examples of irrational algebraic normal numbers exist.

Comment: @Ian So would you be inclined to say that they probably do not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the details of goodness-of-fit tests, you can start by asking a very simple question: What is the probability that I will get $95$ out of a $1000$ digits being `7` if the distribution of digits was "truly random"? (i.e., probability is $0.1$ for each of the digits).

This probability is simply given by the binomial distribution:

$$ {1000 \choose 95} \cdot 0.1^{95} \cdot 0.9^{905} \approx 0.037$$ Pretty low you might think. But what is the probability of having exactly 100 `7`? 
$$ {1000 \choose 100} \cdot 0.1^{100} \cdot 0.9^{900} \approx 0.042$$ Not that different. In fact the probability of the first $1000$ digits to contain $95$ **or** $94$ `7`s is higher than containing exactly $100$ `7`s.

The randomness of the digits of $\pi$ has been extensively studied. Here's a interesting post that discusses the main points: 
http://thestarman.pcministry.com/math/pi/RandPI.html
You might find this quote relevant:

> "Does π's fixed pattern of digits appear as a random stream?"
>   Generally speaking, I would have to say, "Yes." However, depending
>   upon which particular decimal place of π that we stop to add up each
>   of its ten digits1, we may find some peculiarities leading the average
>   person to wonder if this is true.